# Assignment operator and a temporary

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am currently using VS2012 and was expecting statement B in this code to fail since we are passing a temp which is a constant to the assignment operator method in the foo class. Surprisingly that doesnt fail why is that ? Statement A fails and that is fine. Why doesnt statement B fail ?

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    foo& operator=(foo& that)
    {
        a=12;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const foo a;
    foo b;
    //b = a;      //statement A
    b = foo();    //Statement B
}
```

Comment: Latest VS with high warning should warn about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because VC++, with language extensions enabled, is not standard compliant and allows binding a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

After adding a default constructor in `foo`, [both GCC and Clang issue an appropriate error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1db2f5f7e9bc988a):

> main.cpp:18:7: error: no viable overloaded '='
>
> ```
>   b = foo();    //Statement B
>   ~ ^ ~~~~~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:6:10: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value
>   for 1st argument
>
> ```
> foo& operator=(foo&)
>      ^
> ```

Comment: And VC++ does issue an error as well when language extensions are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @hvd Good to know. Don't work with VS actually :o)